# get offset of draggable kendo window

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

How could I get the offset(); of my kendo window while it is being dragged... For instance, in jQuery UI, the below works:

```
$('#easterEgg').draggable(
    {
        drag: function(){
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var xPos = offset.left;
            var yPos = offset.top;


            $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
            $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);
        }
    });
```

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DGbT3/)

But when I try to incorporate the same, with kendo ui, I get nothing: Have tried a few variants of below, no errors, just no output. How can I do the same with kendo ui?

```
$("#easterEgg").kendoWindow({
        draggable: true,

         drag: function(){
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var xPos = offset.left;
            var yPos = offset.top;


            $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
            $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a few mistakes in your code.

First of all, there is no `drag` event, please check the [docs](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#events). You have to use [`dragstart`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window/events/dragstart) or [`dragend`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window/events/dragend) for that.

Second problem is that javascript frameworks differ from each other in their functionalities. Because `this` in jQuery UI is the modal's element doesn't means that its the same for all other frameworks. On Kendo UI `this` keyword in most cases is the widget's instance, which makes much more sense than refering only to the target element. The widget's instance has a property called `element` which is the target element where the widget is created over.

Given that, your code should be:

```
dragstart: function() { // or dragend
    let offset = $(this.element).offset();
}
```

[Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/AZUduJoz)